# Creating a running total with max and min limits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm calculating a running total for battery storage in an electricity grid simulator.

While iterating through each line I need to add the previous value of `surpluses` to the previous value ([i-1]) of `battery` up to a maximum storage capacity of `s`

`surpluses` is often negative so will often drop to a mimimum of 0

**I need to start the iteration from the second value as the first value is** `s`

I have created a series `battery` to iterate through and have tried the following

`surpluses` is also a series

```
for i, item in battery.iteritems()[1]:
    if (battery[i-1] + surpluses[i-1]) < 0:
        battery[i] = 0
    elif (battery[i-1] + surpluses[i-1]) > s:
        battery[i] = s
    else:
        battery[i] = battery[i - 1] + surpluses[i - 1]
```

So for example I want to use `s = 5` as  `battery[0]` then `battery[1] = battery[0] + surplus[0]` and so on.

```
surpluses
-1
-2
 1
-4

battery
5
4
2
3
0
```

In this case, 5 is the max and 0 is the min which is why I have if statements to prevent the running total leaving this range.

**Current errors**

```
if (batteryStorage[i-1] + surpluses[i-1]) < 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

and

````
for i, item in batteryStorage.iteritems()[1]:
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable```
````

Comment: Can you give an example input and output you're looking for?

Comment: I've added an example, thanks @Putnam

Comment: What seems to be the problem in your proposed code? Also it is not clear what is batteryStorage but did you mean to do `batteryStorage.iteritems()[1:]` instead?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, ```batteryStorage``` is meant to be ```batttery```. I have added the current errors, one comes from me trying to start the iteration on the second item ```battery.iteritems()[1]:```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this completely answers your question, but I was able to create a runningTotal for a series with a max and min, using this code:

```
df = pd.Series([1,3,-5,3,2,5,1])
max = 5
min = 0
runningTotal = 0

for index, row in df.iteritems():
    runningTotal = addToRunningTotal(row, runningTotal)

def addToRunningTotal(number, runningTotal):
    if number + runningTotal > max:
        runningTotal = max
    elif number + runningTotal < min:
        runningTotal = min
    else:
        runningTotal+=number
    print(runningTotal)
    return runningTotal
```

I created a function that takes the current row number and the runningTotal, returning the new runningTotal. Using a function makes this slightly easier. You don't have to mess with the [index - 1].

This is the output:

```
1
4
0
3
5
5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Using enumerate allows the reference of other series at the index i.

```
for i, index in enumerate(batteryStorage, start=1):
    if i > len(batteryStorage) - 1:
        break
    elif (batteryStorage[i - 1] + surpluses[i - 1]) < 0:
        batteryStorage[i] = 0
    elif (batteryStorage[i - 1] + surpluses[i - 1]) > inp.batteryStorage:
        batteryStorage[i] = inp.batteryStorage
    else:
        batteryStorage[i] = round(batteryStorage[i - 1] + surpluses[i - 1],0)
```